# Is there a way to compute a hash for all the columns of a SQL Server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 view that has around 12 columns in it, some of them are numbers and some are strings and some others are `DateTime`, I need to add a 13th column that's like a hash of all these ones, currently I am just doing the following

```
column1 +  '|' + column2 +  '|' column3
```

and so on, it is tedious and requires that I cast all the non-varchar columns to `varchar` and do this concatenation.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CHECKSUM to hash the values into an INT in a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 VARCHAR(10), C2 VARCHAR(10), C3 INT, C4 DATETIME, 
C5 AS CHECKSUM(C1, C2, C3, C4))

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 1', 'Col2 Val 1', 100, getdate() - 100)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 2', 'Col2 Val 2', 200, getdate() - 80)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 3', 'Col2 Val 3', 300, getdate() - 60)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 4', 'Col2 Val 4', 400, getdate() - 40)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 5', 'Col2 Val 5', 500, getdate() - 20)
```

C5 yields:

```
C5
-1870891995
-1870901775
-1870904739
-1870874967
-1870880267
```

If you need it to be a readable hash, you can write the hash as a computed column - that way, you'll only need to write it once:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 VARCHAR(10), C2 VARCHAR(10), C3 INT, C4 DATETIME, 
C5 AS C1 + '|' + C2 + '|' + CAST(C3 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '|' + FORMAT(C4, 'M/d/yyyy'))

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 1', 'Col2 Val 1', 100, getdate() - 100)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 2', 'Col2 Val 2', 200, getdate() - 80)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 3', 'Col2 Val 3', 300, getdate() - 60)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 4', 'Col2 Val 4', 400, getdate() - 40)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Value 5', 'Col2 Val 5', 500, getdate() - 20)

SELECT * FROM T1

C5
Value 1|Col2 Val 1|100|5/2/2017
Value 2|Col2 Val 2|200|5/22/2017
Value 3|Col2 Val 3|300|6/11/2017
Value 4|Col2 Val 4|400|7/1/2017
Value 5|Col2 Val 5|500|7/21/2017
```

Comment: I am actually doing that right now, wondering if there is a more elegant way to do the same.

Comment: Hmm... what about CHECKSUM?

Comment: I think that will should work if the output will be unique for a unique combination.